# Where does the term "affine space" come from?

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, math-history

I'm wondering since few years what its origin is. The adjective affinis means neighbouring, allied to, kindred and the noun derived from it affinitas means relationship, connection, union, affinity. I'd appreciate all kind of information, but I'm looking especially for some literature about the etymology of this term.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best that I could find is this webpage on earliest known uses of words in mathematics: http://jeff560.tripod.com/a.html
It provides the following information: Affinis and affinitas were first used by Leonhard Euler in Introductio in analysin infinitorum (1748) Chapter XVIII: "De similitudine et affinitate linearum curvarum." He also wrote (II. xviii. 239): "Quia Curvae hoc modo ortae inter se quandam Affinitatem tenent, has Curvas affines vocabimus."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**This** Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_geometry#History) provides some historical background:

> $$\cdots$$
>   In 1748, Euler introduced the term affine (Latin affinis, "related") in his book *Introductio in analysin infinitorum* (volume 2, chapter XVIII).
>   $$\cdots$$